# How to deal with Picasso OutOfMemoryError?

Tags: android, picasso

I want to show a `ViewPager` with ~50 pages, each containing a different image. Using Picasso, the first 20-25 pages work perfectly. However, at that point I get an `OutOfMemoryError`, and *no* images are loading at all:

```
Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 7477932 byte allocation with 1932496 free bytes"
```

I'm using the following code in my `PagerAdapter`:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    View view = getView();
    Picasso picasso = getImageLoader(mContext);
    picasso.load(getUrl(position)).fit().into((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview));
    container.addView(view);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position, final Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
}
```

What can I do to avoid this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have found [this issue](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/305).

Some points noted:

- Use `skipMemoryCache()`
- Use `builder.executor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());`
- Use *one* instance of `Picasso`: do not create a new instance using `Picasso.Builder` every time.

I managed to fix my problem with the last one.

Comment: Using Picasso.with(context) always works on a Singleton Picasso manages itself, so this should be save to use.

Comment: Picasso was designed to be used as a singleton. Do not allocate multiple instances of Picasso unless you really know what you want to do and how to properly handle it. 99.999% you won't need more than one instance

Comment: skipMemoryCache() helped

Comment: there is no need to `builder.executor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());` in new version of picasso.

Comment: using `.fit()` and/or `.memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE, MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)` is enough.

Comment: Use skipMemoryCache()
Deprecated

Comment: Thank you 'guido mocha' for your comment' this helped me

Answer (score 10):

This question is high ranked on Google hits, so I'm adding my solution to this problem.

Adding `.fit()` solved the problem for me. I'm successfully loading images with below code.

```
picasso.load(PartyUtil.getPartyIconResourceFromFullPartyName(parties.get(position)))
    .fit()
    .into(holder.icon);
```

Removing `.fit()` causes my application to throw an `OutOfMemoryException`.

Comment: Does your ImageView has fixed size? That is, do you set width and height? `fit()` doesn't work for `wrap_content`.

Comment: Yes, in my case the ImageView have a fixed size. @CodePond.org

Comment: @NimrodDayan you can use `.resize(width,height)`.